# Explanation of a html and css trick for label background color

Tags: html, css, background-color

How can I make a performance like following image using HTML and CSS?

[image]

I mean, how the `outlined` label can disappear the border partially? Background color of the label supposedly is transparent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) and [`isolation: isolate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/isolation#isolate) for **masking** parts of the border:

```css
/*Blacks will persist, whites will be transparent*/
.border-label {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.border-label>label {
  /*Position centered on top border*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

/*Ignore, presentational; remaining styles and focus behaviour*/
body {background-color: red}

.input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.input-wrapper>input {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  padding: .6rem .8rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.border-label {
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: border-color .05s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
input:not(:focus)+.border-label {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.border-label>label {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: .2rem;
  padding: .2rem .4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: top .05s;
}

input:not(:focus, :valid)+.border-label>label {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input required>
  <div class="border-label">
    <label>Placeholder label</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough with blend-modes and masking, so someone else may surely be able to **improve my answer**.

Comment: Thanks @Oskar . That is great. But I'm really bewildered how it works! The most strange section is the first one in CSS classes.